# nextcloudpi in docker: Cannot use mounted external storage

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, nextcloud

Recently I installed nextcloudpi in docker with

```
sudo docker run -d -p 4443:4443 -p 443:443 -p 80:80 -v /home/user/storage/nextcloud:/data --name nextcloudpi ownyourbits/nextcloudpi-armhf <ip-adress-of-pi>
```

the folder /home/user/storage is a mounted external storage (following this tutorial https://www.techjunkie.com/build-nas-raspberry-pi-linux/)

It get me the error:

```
Running nc-init

Setting up a clean Nextcloud instance... wait until message 'NC init done'

Setting up database...

Setting up Nextcloud...

Console has to be executed with the user that owns the file config/config.php

Current user: www-data

Owner of config.php: root

Try adding 'sudo -u root ' to the beginning of the command (without the single quotes)

If running with 'docker exec' try adding the option '-u root' to the docker command (without the single quotes)
```

I tried

```
sudo docker run -d -p 4443:4443 -p 443:443 -p 80:80 -v /home/user:/data --name nextcloudpi ownyourbits/nextcloudpi-armhf <ip-adress-of-pi>
```

and everythink workes well as far as I can tell. I can load the nextcloudpi config UI as well as the nextcloud GUI.

I have tried some chown and chmod for the /home/user/storage folder, without any succes.

How can i use the external storage as directory of the nextcloud?